# Is there any way to use a GCHandle or use Marshal in WP8 in a portable class library?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, portable-class-library

I'm trying to use this code in a PCL that I'm hoping to use in a WP8 app:

```
internal static T ByteArrayToStructure<T>(byte[] bytes) where T : struct
{
    GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    T value = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(),
        typeof(T));
    try {}
    finally { handle.Free(); }
    return value;
}
```

However, it doesn't register `GCHandle` or `Marshal`. Is there a way to use these, or is there some other way to do this while using allowed classes?

Comment: Not possible.  This looks like an oversight to me.

Comment: @HansPassant Oh dear :( My whole library's now going to be impossible to build. Thanks for the info!

Comment: You can create a interface defined in the PCL and implement it in your phone code. Pass the interface into the method.

Comment: @ShawnKendrot Is this available in plain WP8 class libraries?

Comment: No, you would implement the concrete class that just wraps calls to GCHandle or whatever specific code you need

Comment: 1) What's the point of your `try...finally` pattern? 2) Why `GCHandle` over `fixed`? 3) If you only need to support specific struct types, you could marshal by hand.

Comment: @CodesInChaos 1) Make sure the handle is freed. 2) I have no idea how to use fixed; this was from a Stack Overflow answer. 3) How would I do that?

Comment: 1) Your `try...finally` has (almost) no effect, since the relevant code isn't inside the `try` block. 2) Something like `fixed(byte* pb = bytes){...}` 3) combining manual array accesses with bitshifts. But you need to write different code for each struct type. I don't know if this is preferable over your code or not, since I don't know enough context.

Comment: @CodesInChaos 1) Right, OK. 2) Thanks! 3) It's for a single type so far so I'm seeing if I can do this manually.